# how to display a specific value a(col#,row#) on a gnuplot chart?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, gnuplot

I realize gnuplot 4.6 does not have a specific data point addressing capability and I would have to use a script to extract a given value and store it as a variable (for example, to extract a value in the 7th column in the 4th row from the last, I simplistically could use `'tail -4 data.out | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'`).  How could I store/assign that value as a gnuplot variable and then display it on a chart with the `set label 1 sprintf("a = %3.4f",a) at x,y` command?

Comment: re-tagged with `windows` and `windows-xp` as those seem to be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot understands backtics the same as your shell.  So, to get at the particular value in your datafile:

```
a=`tail -4 data.dat | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'`
set label 1 sprintf("a=%3.4f",a) at x,y
```

Comment: I'm afraid this promising answer is true for the Linux versions of gnuplot, but when used under Windows XP, I get an error message                      gnuplot> a=
           ^
         "6p.gp", line 15: constant expression required

Comment: @user1537723 -- What does the entire line look like (in gnuplot?)  It's possible your shell command isn't getting what you think it is.  (That seems like a strange error message if gnuplot isn't handling the backtics properly) -- Of course, I'm not at all familiar with how to build a shell command on Windows...

Comment: no luck with this syntax on a Windows XP 32-bit...  Command 'a = system "tail -3 data.out"' generates an error message to the effect that system evaluation is not supported by MS-Windows 32 bit.  However, gnuplot> !tail -4 data.out | head -1 | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/,//' | pg displays the value I'd like to display, so the problem is how to pass it to an internal gnuplot variable.  I've tried a=, redirection inside the parentheses or double quotes etc with no luck.  It looks like a Windows-specific problem...

Comment: @user1537723 can you plot something using "shell redirection" (e.g. `plot "< awk '{print $2,$3}' datafile.dat" u 1:2` ?  It's possible your gnuplot wasn't built with support for pipes ... (which would make sense because from what I know, windows doesn't have `popen`).

Comment: thanks a lot!  I have tried redirection, to no avail...  the awk expression works on a command line, but the redirection in gnuplot doesn't.  hey, there must be a hack out there!  :-)

Comment: You could do this all under cygwin where pipes work.  But I'm not sure if you want to go to all the trouble of installing cygwin and then gnuplot ...

Comment: I've tried using ksh under Windows, but the redirection did not work.  I know there is a gnuplot-pipes.exe Windows version, and will have to check it out to see what it is...

Comment: OK, I finally found an answer to this problem:  use gnuplot_pipes.exe, a version specifically created to handle pipes, redirection etc. on a Windows platform. mgilson, your original answer is the right one when used with gnuplot_pipes.exe, not wgnuplot.exe--thank you.

Comment: @user1537723 I'm glad you found your solution.  If you'd like to add it as a separate answer, feel free.  If not, I'll add that to my answer to make it complete (for others who might have the same problem as you).

Answer (score 0):

When reading something like "can't be done with gnuplot", it "hurts" and encourages me
to nevertheless find a *gnuplot-only* solution which consequently is platform-independent. (See the above comments about Linux and Windows (in)compatibility issues.)
Although, sometimes it's getting cumbersome and less efficient, but sometime it is not much longer than the solution with external tools.

Basically, you can use `stats` and `every` for this (check `help stats` and `help every`), however, if you need the `m`th row from the last, you first need to know how many lines you have in total. That's why you have to run `stats` twice. Check the following example:

**Data:** `SO11560130.dat`

```
  1   21   3   4   5   6   78
  2   25   3   4   5   6   72
  3   23   3   4   5   6   73
  4   29   3   4   5   6   74
  5   27   3   4   5   6   77
  6   28   3   4   5   6   75
  7   22   3   4   5   6   73
  8   24   3   4   5   6   78
  9   26   3   4   5   6   78
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### extract specific value from given row/column
reset

FILE = "SO11560130.dat"

M   = 4     # row from last
COL = 7     # column no.

stats FILE u 0 nooutput       # get total number of lines in variable STATS_records
n = STATS_records - M         # index 0-based
stats FILE u (x0=$1,y0=$2,a=column(COL)) every ::n::n nooutput  # get the value and coordinates

set label 1 sprintf("a=%3.4f",a) at x0,y0 offset 0,1

plot FILE u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]